# Get Data Usage and free space of a Database without being the Owner or Sysadmin?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to know if there is any way to get for every database of an instance the used space and shrinkable space if your are neither the owner or a sysadmin?

Like the `SP_SPACEUSED` stored procedure.

The goal would be to know in which databases it is possible to get space back, so the important data really is the shrinkable space.

Comment: This sounds like you're then planning to shrink said databases. Generally shrinking databases is a bad idea, as it can cause (severe) fragmentation, which causes performance issues.

Comment: Also, if you don't have access to be able to access the free space in said database files, then it's highly unlikely you're going to be able to shrink them. This has the "smell" of an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: Thank you for your anwsers but i am aware of the issues repeatedly shrinking can cause and that without being a Sysadmin or owner of the Database you can't shrink it.
Netherless i want to know if it is possible to get the available free space in the Databases of an SQL server instance.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is really a question for your DBA. If you don't have dbo or sysadmin you may not be able to see or login to all the databases.

Comment: And is there any chance there is a view representing the used space and available space of each Database ? 
Or a database Role that would give you information about the DataBases without having any inforation of the content inside it? (For a matter of privacy)